# WPF Best Practices - Calling commands vs method

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following setup for a commands. DismissCommand calls DismissAlert, which then also needs to refresh. The RefreshCommand calls one method, which will hold the logic to refresh.

My question is this: Is it better to treat the RefreshCommand like a method, and call it whenever I want to do the Refresh action, or should i instead call the method?

I realize they will both have the same effect, the question is which is more clear for other programmers between the two lines notated below.

```
    private ICommand dismissCommand;
    public ICommand DismissCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return dismissCommand ?? (dismissCommand = new RelayCommand((userAlertID) =>
            {
                DismissAlert((int)userAlertID);
            }));
        }
    }

    private ICommand refreshCommand;
    public ICommand RefreshCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return refreshCommand ?? (refreshCommand = new RelayCommand((obj) =>
            {
                LoadAlerts();
            }));
        }
    }

    public void DismissAlert(int userAlertID)
    {
        AlertModel.DismissAlert(userAlertID);
        RefreshCommand.Execute(null); // should I use this line
        LoadAlerts();                 // or this line?
    }
```

Comment: To me it's about how local the Commands/methods are. If it's a local method (i.e. same class/scope/equal) call the method. If it's an ApplicationCommand or similar (which are already invoked by Commands by someone else) but in another class, call the command via execute. I don't think there's a common practice though.. You should perhaps talk to your coworkers about the common practices for the project you are currently working with.

Comment: To expand on my comment, there are things like [`CompositeCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.composite.presentation.commands.compositecommand.aspx)s which would be better to call via the Command so that all of the commands get notified.